# Rasters subtraction gives overlapping cells as output GRASS GIS

Tags: raster, grass-gis, r.mapcalc

I have two rasters, `a` and `b`. I want to subtract cells that in the raster `b` have a 0 value from raster `a`.
So I want to subtract one raster from another, similar to this: [Compare raster maps in GRASS GIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/269729/compare-raster-maps-in-grass-gis)

I followed this tutorial https://baharmon.github.io/map-algebra-in-grass and so far I have written:

`r.mapcalc --o expression="zero_values = if(b == 0,0,null())" #if cells in the b raster equal 0, then write the value of 0 in the new zero_values raster, else write null values`

`r.mapcalc --o expression="without_zero = a - zero_values"`

The problem is that the output is not raster `a` without the raster `zero_values`, but it is a raster containing the cells present in `zero_values` that are overlapping with raster `a`.
I have also tried to assign a value of 1 to the cells of `zero_values`:

`r.mapcalc --o expression="zero_values2 = if(b == 0,1,null())"`

But I have the same problem. I am using GRASS 7.8.6

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally clear on what you're trying to do, but maybe creating a MASK raster will help:

```
r.mapcalc "MASK = if(b == 0,1,null())"
r.mapcalc "without_zero = a"
r.mask -r
```

Comment: I want to remove (subtract) the cells of raster `b` with value 0 that are overlapping with raster `a`. But instead of obtaining a raster `a` without these cells, I was obtaining a raster containing the cells of raster `b` with value 0 that are overlapping with raster `a`. I will check with a mask, thanks!

Comment: Raster is a table with x rows and y columns. You cannot delete cells from the table but cells can be labeled to mean nodata "is cell value = 0 then there is actually no data in the cell" or then it is possible to add a special binary mask band that classifies the cells into data/nodata cells.

Comment: @Micha it works, but with `r.mapcalc "MASK = if(b == 1,1,null())"` (probably I wasn't clear on what I wanted to get). Thanks as always!
@user20184 thanks for clarifying.

Comment: In the original question it says: "...subtract cells that in the raster b have a 0 value". But as long as you're getting what you expect, that's fine.